# Subsurf modifier and texturing the UV

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I am planning on texturing my object in substance painter, however, most of my objects (like the one in my photo with its UV map at zero subsurf level) have used subsurf modifier and the UV map of the same object before and after applying subsurf modifier are very different and I worry that people who download my model prefer using other subsurf levels but my texture maps are all painted at certain sursurf levels (e.g. level 2 subsurf).

What is the common practice in texturing objects that have used subsurf modifiers? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you could apply the subsurf before unwrapping, obviously, to get perfect matching...

Comment: @m.ardito Thanks, but what if those who downloaded the model prefer a lower or higher subdivision level to be used? For example, I published a model at subsurf level 2 but the downloader somehow want level 1 or 3 during their render?